# Doctrine / ExtJS: Use model to create another model

Tags: php, extjs, doctrine, shopware

I'm having difficulties implementing some of the features my client would like to have.
We're building a shopware shop, which is almost done. I've developed some plugins and customizations to have the shop fit my client, but I'm not the best at backend development using ExtJS and Doctrine.

The situation is: The shop sells car parts. We've bought a third-party plugin that allows us to enter ktype numbers for each product, so that the client can search for his/her car in the frontend and get all fitting products.
The plugin has it's own window in the backend, which isn't very comfortable.
So I created an extra tab in the article details, which displays all entries from the database using the third-party model.
That wasn't so hard since the model and database were created by the third-party plugin and I just had to query the data and display it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is: I added an extra column (selected) with a checkbox, where the admin can choose the cars the article fits to.
The plan was to read the textfield "ktypes" of the article on load, check all corresponding checkboxes and then when a checkbox is altered just save the new ktypes array to the article.

Problem is, that this way I can't sort by that column since it's not in the ExtJS store/model.

So now I'm thinking I'll create my own Model with all the columns from the third-party model, add a article_id column and a selected column and reference everything there.

What I don't know is: How to I get the contents of the third-party model into my own database?
The third-party plugin doesn't reference the article. The table only holds all car data imported from a csv list. The reference between an article and the data is just a textfield in the article details.

I thought about Doctrine associations, but I don't really have a reference point or foreign key...

Has anyone got an idea how to solve this?
Can share code if that helps...

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Stefan, i think it would help if you would share some code. Right now its a bit hard to face the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I went in a different direction but still need help. Will post a new question though since it's a different topic.

Thanks for trying to help!